# Project Stage[Development]: Unhandled Messages - JSF

Tags: validation, jsf

I get two validation messages; one correct and then one at the top of the form, when the mouse is over it says "Project Stage[Development]: Unhandled Messages". How can I hide this message?

```html
<h:outputLabel for="username">Please enter your username: </h:outputLabel>
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{user.id}" required="true">
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="usernameMessage" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message id="usernameMessage" for="username" />
```

userBean.java

```java
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@NotNull(message="The username can not be blank")
@Size(min=6, max=12, message="Please enter a valid username (6-12 characters)")
private String id;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

web.xml

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a development warning which should indicate that the developer made a mistake. You shouldn't have unhandled faces messages at all. Provide the proper `<h:message>` and make sure that it's updated on ajax requests as well.

```
<h:message for="Username" />
```

Or, provide at least a generic `<h:messages>` which shows all messages.

```
<h:messages/>
```

This warning (and the whole list of unhandled messages) will disappear once you set the JSF project stage to `Production`.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Or just remove the whole context parameter altogether; it defaults to `Production` already.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your `<h:outputLabel for>` attribute is wrong, it does not match the ID of the input component. Or, rather, the ID of the input component does not follow standard HTML/CSS code conventions. It should be `camelCase`, not `TitleCase`. So, use

```
<h:outputLabel for="username" ... />
<h:inputText id="username" ... />
<h:message for="username" ... />
```

That's *after all* also a potential main cause of your concrete problem. That you have properly used the `<h:message for="username"/>` but it couldn't display the message due to the input component using an invalid component ID `Username`.

Comment: I experience a similar error. To solve it, i have to place h:message after the components that it is for. Is there a way to place h:message/s before the component so that it renders above it?